# Error in SAP Gateway service for Fiori My Leave Request

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-gateway

I am trying to implement My Leave Request App. I have I have implemented all the SAP Notes and Add-on Components mentioned in

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_fiori/fiori10_install_en.pdf

But when I try to execute the service ZLEAVEREQUEST in the Gateway Client I am getting the following error

Model 'ZLEAVEREQUEST_0002_BE' contains errors. Contact Adminstrator

Please help me fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log on to the Front End System

Transaction: **SPRO**

Click on **SAP Reference IMG**

Browse to: **SAP Netweaver -> Gateway -> OData Channel -> Configuration -> Connection Settings 
           -> SAP Netweaver Gateway to SAP System -> Manage SAP System Aliases**

Select the SAP System Alias name and uncheck **Local GW** and **For Local App** both the check boxes.

This will resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the correction notes are applied . You can check the SAP Service Market place to find the available support packages. Also make sure all the relevant Business Catalog Roles are assigned to the user.